# Export Blender materials to Unity3D

Tags: unity, blender

I have a low poly model that I made in Blender 2.8. Because it's low poly, it only has a material that's a mix between a diffuse and a glossy shader - it has no textures. The only thing I want to do is import the model into Unity3D with the diffuse and glossy shaders, just like it is in Blender. 

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: You can't use blender materials in unity. Unity have it own materials.

Comment: Diffuse and glossy effects are both supported by the default Unity standard shader you get on newly imported content. Have you had any difficulty configuring this one to have the visual effect you want?